# C++ : How to substitute structure member type string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I want my string to comprised of blanks too. So I used `getline` not `cin`.
I want to substitute SearchStd->StdName to NewName. So I used strcpy.
But I can't do that because string type isn't char array.
So I want to know what should I replace strcpy with, to substitute string type of structure member.

```
struct Subject {    //과목 정보 
string SubName; //과목 이름 
int Hakjum;         //과목 학점 
char Grade[10];     //과목 평점 
float GPA;          // 과목 평점
};

struct Student {    //학생 정보 
string StdName; //학생 이름 
int Hakbun;         //학번 
Subject *Sub;       //과목 
int SubNum;         //과목 수 
float AveGPA;       //교과목 평균
};

void ModifyStdInfo(Student *pSt, int StudentNum){           //학생 정보 수정
Student* SearchStd;
SearchStd = StdSearch(pSt, StudentNum);
if(SearchStd != NULL){
    string NewName;
    int NewHakbun=0;
    cout<<"* ("<<SearchStd->StdName<<", "<<SearchStd->Hakbun<<")의 정보를 수정하세요\n";
    cout<<"이름 :";
    getline(cin, NewName);
    cout<<NewName<<endl;
    strcpy((*SearchStd).StdName, NewName);
    cout<<"학번 : ";
    cin>>NewHakbun;
    SearchStd->Hakbun=NewHakbun;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) to copy `std::string`.

```
(*SearchStd).StdName = NewName;
```

Comment: Might as well use `->`